# Help proving that a measure is absolutely continuous with respect with respect to another measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose that $E$ is a locally compact and separable metric space, let $\mathcal{B}_E$ denote the set of its Borel subsets and suppose that $\mu$ is a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal{B}_E)$. In addition, suppose that $p:E\times \mathcal{B}_E\to[0,1]$ is a stochastic kernel such that

- For any $B\in\mathcal{B}_E$, $p(\cdot,B):E\to[0,1]$ is a measurable map.
- For any $x\in E$, $p(x,\cdot):\mathcal{B}_E\to[0,1]$ is a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal{B}_E)$.

Suppose that $\mu$ is an invariant probability measure of $p$. That is, for any $B\in \mathcal{B}_E$ we have that

$$\mu(B) =\int p(x,B)\mu(dx).\quad\quad$$

I'm trying to prove (or disprove) that necessarily it is the case that for $\mu$-almost every $x\in E$, $p(x,\cdot)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ (that is, that $\mu(B)=0\Rightarrow p(x,B)=0$ for all $B\in\mathcal{B}_E$). Could someone provide a hint that'll help derive a proof or find a counterexample (or suggest a reference where I could find such)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $B$ is such that $\mu(B)=0$, then $p(x,B)=0$ for $\mu$-almost every $x$ (because $x\mapsto p(x,B)$ is non-negative). *But* the almost everywhere here depends on $B$.

Define for $x\in\mathbb R$ and $B$ a Borel subset,
$$p(x,B)=\begin{cases}1&\mbox{ if }x\in B;\\
0&\mbox{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Each measure is invariant.

Comment: That settles it, thanks.